# What are some benefits of clearing a Windows Event Log?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

An admin on my network says he was troubleshooting an issue and had cleared the event logs.

Is this a problem? What are some of the benefits of clearing the event viewer logs while troubleshooting software issue(s)?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: May be your admins also have SF accounts? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It provides a clean slate allowing you to disregard all the prior "noise" and focus on the new errors.

Answer (score 1):

If cleaning logs can provide a better overview during a troubleshooting session, it can also be considered as a critical security issue.

Actually, cleaning logs generates 2x event IDs (1102 & 104) that are commonly used in SOCs (Security Operation Center) with specific SIEM rules or use cases. 
So I wouldn't suggest to clear logs in general since it may create false positive incident. Instead, I would suggest to use the Event Viewer filter, the logs export feature or a SIEM solution.